# Adding a blank space in HTML using 'div' and CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I want to add a blank space between my divs.

I tried adding 1 div and then using properties in CSS like margin-top, padding-top, etc... every other thing I can find on the internet. The only thing that adds space is when I use margin-top:2000px or more...

That gives me a horrible huge space. The div is empty, it has nothing in it.

Can someone please tell me how can I add some vertical space between 2 divs? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code here? Preferably at http://jsbin.com/

Comment: *That gives me a horrible huge space* because 2000 is much more value.  margin-top is the correct way to have space between two divs

Answer (score 5):

Some browsers don't like to display empty tags. Try adding a period or a sticky space inside. A sticky space is a code that browsers display as spaces. Just enter &nbsp ; inside your spacer div, but without the space before the semicolon.
Alternatively, you could use break tags (<br>) to fill in the space, or a transparent spacer image set to the height you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use margin, padding or put a block element between them with a certain height.
But without seeing your code it's hard to tell why is margin-top: 2000px only working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem using div as blank space. Just create a blank div with padding and some attributes that might help you.

```
.yourBlankSpaceDivClass {
   padding: 20px 30px; // blank div(or blank space) height and width. Depends on you.
   position: absolute; // so that you can place the blank div(or blank space) wherever you want it. Make sure you have a "position: relative;" div. Absolute div must be inside a Relative div.
   top: 0; // Depends on you.
   left: 0; // Depends on you.
}
```